# Allow a service once a month code in JSP

Tags: jsp, date, calendar

I have a service(say filling in a form) on a JSP page for a number of users and i want the users to be allowed just once a month(month start and ending dates should work according to calendar). Can anyone tell me how i can do this or give me a sample code? Any links to already implemented such method would be appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On server side you can manage a `Map` per user in the session data (and database). The values are boolean-flags indicating if a user has used the service or not. As map keys you can use a unique combination of year and month as integer, for example the formula `year * 12 + (month - 1)` (here: month starting at one).

Then every form call can evaluate this map to decide if the user has already used the service in current month. If not and the user uses the once-a-month-service then the map and its representation in storage layer on server side need to be updated accordingly.

Update:

For storage of the suggested `Map` you have to note that all relational databases I know don't explicitly support this data type. But you can model it as table with two columns (user key and year-month-key) for example, where every db-record stands for usage of service in given month.

Comment: Thanks! I really hope this can help me have an idea at least :)

Comment: @IbrahimNadir One thing to consider is also the timezone reference year and month are related to. Probably you should just use UTC, for example when instantiating a `java.util.GregorianCalendar` to extract current year and month (attention: there zero-based month).

Comment: Yes i totally understood your point there and i had this in mind but thank you for your comprehensive guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a `Map` is not the best option as your service is not going to be running 24/7(might be, but you shouldnt trust in it). So you need to store, this means persistence, the information about when a user used your service for the last time.

Once you have this data stored you can check the dates by using java's `Calendar`.

Hope this will help!

Comment: The map I suggested has indeed a time information using the right abstraction for the given problem. It is not really interesting on which day or even millisecond in the month the user had used the service to ensure that the user uses the service only once per month. The suggested form of map keys exactly addresses this detail. Anyway, the exact time of last use of service can also be stored for other purposes, but is not directly related to the question.